# How to use 'deep method' in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue component like below. 
And I want to use watch for a specific keyword not everything.
So I made a computed function to focus it.
The code below works very well.

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    foo() {
      return this.item.foo;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    foo() {
      console.log('Foo Changed!');
    }
  },
  data: {
    item: {
      foo: 'foo'
    }
  }
})
```

And I applied to my example. In this case, it doesn't work well. So I guess it should be used by 'deep: true' inside of 'changedOptions' of watch. But I don't know how can I use 'deep' inside of a function.Could you recommend some solutions?

```
data(){
   return {
       deliveryOptions: {
           weight: 3,
           options: { express: false, shuttle: false, bike: true, walk: false },
   },



 computed: {changedOptions() {
             return this.deliveryOptions.options;
            }
 },

 watch: {
    changedOptions(){
        console.log('changed')
    }
 }
```

Comment: Isn't this just example `c` from the docs? https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch

Comment: Ah, You're right. Thank you so much for your inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed only runs when you use computed value somewhere.

you can either use it in the template part or in the script.

lets us use it in mounted like below

```
mounted () {
  console.log(this.changedOptions)
  // this will call the computed to return the value.
}
```

if the watcher still doesn't run then you can try immediate: true in watcher like below

```
 watch: {
    changedOptions: {
       immediate: true, 
       handler () {
          console.log('changed')
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Adding a watcher for a computed property counts as 'using' it. You don't have to use it somewhere else for the watcher to be called.